# Can anyone identify this chrysalis?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What kind of chrysalis or pupa is this? It’s about an inch and 3/4 long and is hanging off the brick siding of a house in Piedmont North Carolina. It wiggles when it is touched. It has been hanging there for at least two or three weeks.[image: brown pupa on brick wall]